# Why isn't my payload sent with this POST request?

Tags: php

I'm trying send a POST request to my API, with a payload ($data).

```
  $api = new CoindRPC();
  $txninfo = $api->gettransaction($argv[1]);
  $txinforaw = $api->getrawtransaction($txninfo['txid']);
  error_log('=== WALLETNOTIFY ===');
  error_log('txninfo: '. print_r($txninfo,true));
  $page_containing_sender = file_get_contents('http://redacted.com/api/getrawtransaction?txid=' . $txninfo['txid'] . '&decrypt=1');
  $sender_parent_obj = json_decode($page_containing_sender, true);
  $possible_senders = $sender_parent_obj['vout'][0]['scriptPubKey']['addresses'];
  $encoded_possible_senders = json_encode($possible_senders);
  echo json_encode($possible_senders);
  $url = 'https://redacted.com/api/register_domain_name';
  foreach($txninfo['details'] as $id => $details) {
     $data = array(
        'txid'     => $txninfo['txid'],
        'tot_amt'  => $txninfo['amount'],
        'tot_fee'  => $txninfo['fee'],
        'confirmations'=> $txninfo['confirmations'],
        'comment'  => $txninfo['comment'],
        'blocktime'=> $txninfo['blocktime'] ? $txninfo['blocktime']:$txninfo['time'],
        'account'  => $details['account'],
        'address'  => $details['address'],
        'category' => $details['category'],
        'amount'   => $details['amount'],
        'fee'      => $details['fee'],
        'possible_senders' => $encoded_possible_senders,
     );
  }
  $options = array(
     'http' => array(
        'header'=> array(
           'WWW-Authenticate: Token',
           'Authorization: Token [redacted]',
           'Accept: application/json',
           'Content-type: application/json'
        ),
        'method'=> 'POST',
        'content'=> json_encode($data),
     ),
  );
  $context = stream_context_create($options);
  $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

At my API, I get a 500 because, whenever I try to retrieve the POST data, I see that there is none. Does anyone know what's wrong? I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

What I've tried: changing json_encode to http_build_query, with changing Accept to the appropriate type for http_build_query, and Content-type to the appropriate type for http_build_query.

Comment: Try to use CURL instead of `file_get_contents`

Comment: if it's your API, as you mention, then you can log onto the API server and see what caused the 500 error, exactly. Also, if it's your API, you should surely know whether it can accept JSON data, or not, and what format is required? Maybe you should show how you are trying to retrieve the POST data precisely.

Comment: And we have no idea if/why your attempt using http_build_query failed, because you didn't show exactly what you did. But on the other point, I agree with Illya, for anything more than a really basic HTTP request, it's generally easier to use cURL.